# Работа двух потоков при обращении к одному элементу

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

У меня есть программа задача которой добавлять и удалять значения из словаря. Изначально программа работала в один поток и две функции выполнялись последовательно, но я хотел увеличить скорость обработки и разделить выполнение на 2 потока.
Программа работает корректно до того момента, когда нужно удалить или добавить элемент в словарь, после добавления/удаления обязательно отключается один из потоков. Чтение словаря проходит без остановок потоков.
Пробовал применять Lock, но эффекта не дало, наверное что-то не так сделал.
Подскажите как сделать так чтобы потоки не отключались?

```
main_dict = {}

def main_open():
    # Результатом работы этой функции является добавление нового элемента в словарь
    main_dict[clue1] = value


def main_close():
    # Результатом работы этой функции является удаление элемента из словаря
    del main_dict[clue2]


main_open = threading.Thread(target=main_open)
main_close = threading.Thread(target=main_close)
main_open.start()
main_close.start()
```

Comment: вот так пробовали https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/58144/using-a-global-dictionary-with-threads-in-python ?

Comment: А где ваш код с Lock?

Answer (score 3):

- Вы забыли после `start()` сделать `join()`, таким образом вы бросаете потоки на произвол судьбы, а не ждёте их завершения
- Что касается добавления и удаления элементов, словарь в `Python` [потокобезопасен, пока вы не пытаетесь по нему итерироваться](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358770/python-dictionary-is-thread-safe)
- `Lock` прекрасно работает, если вам нужно обеспечить атомарность неких связанных операций, проблема скорее всего у вас в чём-то другом (в том, что вы итерируетесь по элементам словаря, который используете в нескольких потоках?)

В общем, нужно больше сведений о том, **что ещё делает ваш код**, чтобы можно было понять, в чём же проблема.

Возможно, вам вообще нужен для вашей задачи не словарь, а, например, очередь `deque`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я нашел решение в котором полностью отказался от общего словаря

Answer (score 0):

Обращаться к одному и тому же объекту в потоках не очень правильно, поскольку начинается конкуренция.
Лучше создать отдельный словарь для функции добавления и отдельный для функции удаления, затем запустить потоки по этим двум словарям и по завершению всех потоков просто соединить словари.